# Has anyone used UADetector?

Tags: java, parsing, user-agent, tablet, mobile-devices

i need to distinguish between desktop vs mobile vs tablet and need to know if it's reliable.i am looking at two libraries UADetector and UAAgentInfo.java.Has anyone have any experience with same?
Also realized that in order to use UADetector i will need to get atleast 6 jar files in my codebase.

I am not sure if this is correct place to ask this question. if not please direct me to correct forum.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is this library wurfl that can help you out. It has a large database of devices. I'm not really sure about the licensing since it changed.

See http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. i am looking for some free library. unfortunately WURFL is licensed.